# Как считывать цифры после перехода на новую строку?

Tags: java, ввод

есть задача, принять от пользователя список цифр , первую строку пропустить, остальные сложить, вроде легко, но я остановился в самом начале, не могу считать все цифры от пользователя) , получается только первую строку, цифры идут каждая на новой строке, формат такой:
3
76363
574
7363
Как считать весь пользовательский ввод?Пытаюсь через ListIterator

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(scan.nextLine().split("\n")));
        ListIterator lis= arr.listIterator();
        while(lis.hasNext()){

        System.out.print(lis.next());}
    }
}
```

Comment: Каждая цифра на новой строке.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте ввести количество чисел, потом запустите цикл for чтобы считать один за одним, а потом усложняйте уже как вы описали

Comment: Я не знаю количество чисел, числа вводит пользователь

Comment: Не считает так цикл фор, там каждые число на новой строчке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вот что имел в виду. А дальше уже усложняйте как вам надо

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter num of vals: ");

        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        array = new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter numbers:");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("\nYour array: ");
        for (int val: array) {
            System.out.print(val + " ");
        }
    }
```